# Using HashSet.orderBy() function

Tags: c#

Trying to sort:

```
HashSet<int> objHash = new HashSet<int>();
objHash.Add(14);
objHash.Add(12);
objHash.Add(11);
objHash.Add(13);
```

`HashSet` contians method `OrderBy()` with definition:

```
IOrderEnumerable<int> IEnumerable<int>.OrderBy<int,TKey>(Func<int,TKey>keySelector)
```

[image]

Trying to understand description:

`IOrderEnumerable<int>`- function `OrderBy()` returns

`IEnumerable<int>` - extension method defined in `IEnumerable<int>`. Can I somehow see body of this method?

`.OrderBy<int,TKey>(Func<int,TKey>keySelector)` - `keySelector` is function delegate with parameter of type `int` that returns `TKey`

Please, correct where my description interpretation is wrong.

How to use this function to order items in `objHash` according custom defined rules?

Comment: Note that you cannot order the elements within the HashSet itself. `OrderBy` returns an IEnumerable that lets you iterate over the elements of the hashset in an ordered manner. The hashset itself remains "unordered", so to speak. If you want to have the HashSet itself ordered, use a SortedSet instead of a HashSet...

Comment: `HashSet` does not contain the method `OrderBy` - `OrderBy` is an extension method (as seen in the description) on `IEnumerable<>` that returns a new `IOrderedEnumerable<>`.

Comment: How I can find `OrderBy` method body?

Answer (score 1):

> keySelector is function delegate with parameter of type int that
>   returns TKey

Yes this is correct.

> How to use this function to order items in objHash according custom
>   defined rules?

Firstly, note that `OrderBy` is an extension method on `IEnumerable` and not a contained method of `HashSet`.

if you want to order the elements via the `OrderBy` extension method then you'd pass `x => x` as the `keySelector` function:

```
var orderedEnumerable = objHash.OrderBy(x => x); // or any other logic as long as the function takes an int and returns TKey
```

Note that this doesn't modify the source and it wouldn't make sense to sort a `HashSet` anyway as by definition it does not care about order.

As [explicitly stated in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, **and whose
>   elements are in no particular order**.

it then goes on to say:

> A `HashSet<T>` collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate
>   elements. **If order or element duplication is more important than
>   performance for your application, consider using the `List<T>` class
>   together with the Sort method**.

Emphasis mine.

if you want to maintain a *sorted set* then consider using `SortedSet` as it's documented as:

> Represents a collection of objects that is maintained in **sorted order**.

Comment: I think it would be good to specify that `OrderBy` is an extension method on `IEnumerable` and not a contained method of `HashSet`. Also note there is nothing about an extension method that says it can't modify its first argument, nor does it need to return a new object.

Comment: @NetMage Right. edited to remove ambiguity. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the quick info on the function correctly. To sort by your custom logic, you need to define what will be the return type as `Tkey` and pass the function that matches the delegate. The order by will then sort based on the returned value.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var h = new HashSet<int> () {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    var d = h.OrderBy<int, int>(x => MyFunc(x));

    foreach(var a in d)
        Console.WriteLine(a); //will order based on the returned value of MyFunc(x). in descending order.
        // output will be 5 4 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3 4 5.
}

public static int MyFunc(int x) 
{
    return x * -1;
}
```

And of course, if your `Tkey` is an `object`, you should want to implement `IComparable` to tell how to sort that object.

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderBy()` method accepts the elements of your collection of objects (in your case, it is an `int` collection) and it should return a **key** for each specific object in the collection. Those **returned keys** are what will be used to **sort the collection**. Notice that these returned keys should be comparable between each other, so that the sorting can be performed.

Let's say you want to sort your numbers, while separating even numbers from odd numbers. A naive way of doing this would be making `OrderBy()` return `string`-typed keys, while placing a "0" character prefix on **even numbers** and a "1" character prefix on **odd numbers**, like that:

```
Number   Returned key
14       "014"
12       "012"
11       "111"
13       "113"
```

Then you can do it like:

```
var ordered = objHash.OrderBy(n => $"{n % 2}{n}");
foreach (var x in ordered)
    Console.WriteLine($"   {x}");
```

This would output numbers in the following order: `12, 14, 11, 13` (first the ordered **even** numbers, followed by the ordered **odd** numbers). Notice how the **returned string keys** were used for comparison/sorting of the set of numbers.

Of course the lexicographical ordering here only works fine because numbers have the same length... But again: this is just a naive example of how to use the `OrderBy()` method.